# Having issue while trying to install esim directly into android phone

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, android-studio

I am working on a flutter app where i am trying to download esim with the lpa code. It's basically an operator app but there are no package for esim installation in flutter or pub.dev. So i had to use android native code with kotlin to run this functionality i am accessign it through method channel in flutter. I am using code from android docs for implenenting esim it leads to an action after tapping ob install button but when i tap on the button on the dialog box it does nothing and the dialog box is from system image.

[image]

When i tap on yes nothing is happening. Here is my code i'm using method channel to access this in flutter.

```
class MainActivity: FlutterFragmentActivity() {

private val CHANNEL1 = "com.demo.methodchannel"

private const val DOWNLOAD_ACTION = "download_subscription"
private const val BROADCAST_PERMISSION = "com.your.company.lpa.permission.BROADCAST"

private val TEST_SIM_PROFILE =
        "LPA:1\$MTAwMDAwMDAwMzQ2MzM5Y2E2NDgwNQ==$7UMyhYJKZLBfHZt2ve9vQH0oKvE=$"

 @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.P)
    private lateinit var manager: EuiccManager
    // Global variable to compare equality missing in android docs
    private var resultIntent: Intent? = null

    private val ACTION_DOWNLOAD_SUBSCRIPTION = "download_subscription"
    private val ACTIVATION_CODE = "LPA:1\$rsp.truphone.com\$JQ-1WDSUO-1IS1KON"
    private var mgr: EuiccManager? = null
    private val Success = "Success"


    @RequiresApi(VERSION_CODES.P)
    override fun configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
        super.configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine)
        MethodChannel(flutterEngine.dartExecutor.binaryMessenger, CHANNEL1).setMethodCallHandler {
                call, result ->
            if (call.method == "messageFunction") {
                manager = getSystemService(EUICC_SERVICE) as EuiccManager
                //setupEsim()
                downloadTestProfile()

            } else {
                result.notImplemented()
            }
        }
    }

 private val eSimBroadcastReceiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
        @SuppressLint("UnsafeIntentLaunch")
        @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.P)
        override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {

            /**
             * Check if same action is triggered again after the allow permission dialog.
             * if not will throw IntentSender.SendIntentException again fails to be mentioned clearly on android docs
             */
            if (resultIntent?.action.equals(intent.action)) {
                return
            }

            val detailedCode =
                intent.getIntExtra(EXTRA_EMBEDDED_SUBSCRIPTION_DETAILED_CODE, 0 /* defaultValue*/)
            val embeddedOperationCode =
                intent.getIntExtra(EXTRA_EMBEDDED_SUBSCRIPTION_OPERATION_CODE, 0 /* defaultValue*/)

            /**
             * Helps if there is an issue with the e-sim
             * Try to print the extras to get all the info like subject or result code.
             */
            print("detailedCode: $detailedCode")
            print("embeddedOperationCode: $embeddedOperationCode")

            when (resultCode) {
                EuiccManager.EMBEDDED_SUBSCRIPTION_RESULT_OK -> {
                    // Success
                    Toast.makeText(
                        this@MainActivity,
                        "Successfully installed eSIM",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                    ).show()
                }

                EuiccManager.EMBEDDED_SUBSCRIPTION_RESULT_RESOLVABLE_ERROR -> {
                    // Recoverable might be permission issue system will show dialog to allow or deny

                    val callbackIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                        baseContext,
                        1 /* requestCode */,
                        intent,
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT or PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE
                    )
                    try {
                        manager?.startResolutionActivity(
                            this@MainActivity,
                            0 /* requestCode */,
                            intent,
                            callbackIntent
                        )
                    } catch (e: IntentSender.SendIntentException) {
                        print(e)
                    }
                }

                else -> Toast.makeText(
                    this@MainActivity,
                    "Failed to install eSIM",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                ).show()
            }
            resultIntent = intent // Assign the intent to the global var for reference
        }
    }

    /**
     * Register the broadcast receiver
     */
    @SuppressLint("UnspecifiedRegisterReceiverFlag")
    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        registerReceiver(
            eSimBroadcastReceiver,
            IntentFilter(DOWNLOAD_ACTION),
            BROADCAST_PERMISSION,
            null
        )
    }

    /**
     * Un-Register the broadcast receiver
     */
    override fun onStop() {
        super.onStop()
        unregisterReceiver(eSimBroadcastReceiver)
    }


    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.P)
    private fun downloadTestProfile() {
        manager = getSystemService(EUICC_SERVICE) as EuiccManager
        // Check if e-sim is supported by the device note that emulators are not supported.
        if (!manager.isEnabled) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "eSIM is not supported on this device", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            return
        }
        val info = manager.euiccInfo
        val osVer = info?.osVersion
        print("osVer $osVer")

        val subscription =
            DownloadableSubscription.forActivationCode(PROFILE)
        val callbackIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
            baseContext,
            0 /* requestCode */,
            Intent(DOWNLOAD_ACTION),
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT or PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE
        )
        manager.downloadSubscription(subscription, true, callbackIntent)
    }
```

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <permission android:protectionLevel="signature" android:name="com.your.company.lpa.permission.BROADCAST" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.your.company.lpa.permission.BROADCAST"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EMBEDDED_SUBSCRIPTIONS"
        tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
```

Comment: Is it working for you? Can you please share your findings?

Comment: Yes working for me but through different approach.

Comment: What was the approach? Can you please describe me?

Comment: Sorry for late response, i used intent and launched lpa through it which leads me to download esim.